# What is the reaction force of centripetal force? Can centrifugal force be its reactive force? But both of them act on differnet bodies right?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

In my textbook it is written that centrifugal force is not the reactive force of centripetal force because it acts on differnet bodies. Then what will be the reactive force (as Newton's 3rd law states that every action has an equal and opposite reaction)

Comment: Centripetal force is not a kind of force. Centripetal force is a label that we put on any force which makes something move in a circle.

Answer (score 1):

Fictitious forces arise in non-inertial reference frames where Newton's laws no longer hold. If you bring in fictitious forces to keep Newton's second law valid, then you invalidate the third law. Fictitious forces have no reaction force associated with them; they just arise from doing calculations in non-inertial frames. Physically they are just the effects of inertia, not due to actual forces.

As as for the centripetal force, it's reaction force is just from the object acting on whatever is supplying the centripetal force. For example if the object is attached to a string, the string pulls on the object, and the reaction force is the object pulling on the string

Comment: In my early mechanics course I recall they called the reaction force to the centripetal force a "reactive centrifugal force" but emphasized that it is not the same thing as the inertial centrifugal force. It was just the name given to the reaction to the centripetal force. Has that terminology changed? Maybe I am out of date.

Comment: @BobD I have heard of that terminology, but it's only been on this site. That term was never taught to me. I'll put that qualifier in my answer just in case though.

Comment: @BobD That terminology is generally unhelpful and confusing, and the only source I ever found for it is a Wikipedia page that referenced one obscure (and old) book. It's not your fault that you were subjected to it while you were learning mechanics, though! (There is nothing wrong or confusing about Aaron Stevens' second paragraph though, IMO)

Comment: @alephzero I'm guessing the teacher felt he needed to give the reaction force a name. But you're right. It's just a reaction force. BTW I do see now that Wiki uses the term.

Comment: @BobD Yeah, I have gotten into confusing conversations with new users on this site before where they are using the wiki article about the reactive centrifugal force but don't realize it. Then they cite it to show that I am wrong, and I have to point out to them that the reactive centrifugal force is not the same thing as the fictitious/inertial one.